# ionic framework and firebase: greeting user when they are logged in

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

How would I go about greeting the user with a toast when they log in, and notifying that they are logged out when they open the app (if they happen to be logged out) or when they log out? I only want to do this once, currently I would need to set this up for every page, which means that each time the user changes the page, they are greeted with a toaster which says "You are currently logged in". This is not convenient, and I would only like to show the toast ONCE, when the app is opened, and when the user logs in.

This is what's currently checking whether they are logged in or not:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.toast.create({
          message: 'You are currently logged in.',
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      } else {
        this.toast.create({
          message: 'You are currently logged out. Access user features by clicking "Log in", located at upper right corner.',
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      }
    });
  }
```

And that is currently only called on the main page. Which means if the user logs in from another tab (user can log in from 4 different tabs), they will not be greeted with the toast, as the toast is currently only on the main page. If I were to use the same code on every page, it would mean that if user logs in on the main page, they would be greeted with the toast. If they now navigate to the profile page, they would be greeted again with the toast. I only want this to be called either when the user logs out, when the user opens the app and when the user logs in. Not on every page. I hope that I have made myself clear.

Comment: you have a tab component?

Comment: @theblindprophet Yes, I do have a tab component. Should I call it there? And if so, how would I call it there? I'm can't call a viewOnLoad function in a tab component, can I?